# Loading Materialize with jQuery will make Waves broken?

Tags: jquery, materialize

The example i have written below, will load materialize.js with jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize.css">
    
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Hello world</p>
      <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Button</a>
  </body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js",
        dataType: "script"
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Doing so, makes the  **Waves** on buttons broken. It simply wont work.
However, Modals and other things still work if i do **M.AutoInit();**

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am in a special situation where i must load it with jQuery. So i cant put the script tag inside the html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Call `Waves.displayEffect();` when the javascript has been loaded.